# What is Happening During Particle Collisions if Particle Location is Defined by a Wave Function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, wavefunction

**My question:** What is Happening During Particle Collisions if Particle Location is Defined by a Wave Function?

From my understanding, we can define particle location by a probabilistic wave function from Schrodinger's equation. So the particle doesn't exist in one exact spot naturally.

So what actually happens then when two particles "collide" (which does seem to imply a single location of contact, at least in classical mechanics)? My guess would be it counts as being "measured" and the wave function collapses to a single location for each particle, but I'm unsure what interaction between the particles would cause it to count as a "measurement" (measurement might be the wrong word but I don't know a more generic term for this).

Maybe I'm not fully grasping wave-particle duality here in this specific case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wavepackets go in and wavepackets come out. Because it's all just a multi-particle state evolving with time. See http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/aqm/topics6.pdf

Comment: The interactions of elementary particles are successfully  modeled by quantum field theory and the mainstream physics is the standard model . The calculational tool of Feynman diagrams models the interaction of point particles , but only the probabilities are predictive. So "happens" is the diagram.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram